# Fit imageView to screen without changing scaletype attribute

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm making app in which images can be zoomed in and out, So I'm using matrix Scale type
But some of the image don't fit screen(can't use scaletype fit xy). How can I fit image to full screen without changing scaletype

```
   import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.graphics.Matrix;
   import android.graphics.PointF;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.FloatMath;
   import android.view.MotionEvent;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;
   import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView imageDetail;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    PointF startPoint = new PointF();
    PointF midPoint = new PointF();
    public RelativeLayout myL;

    float oldDist = 1f;
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            imageDetail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageDetail.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            /** * set on touch listner on image */
    imageDetail.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    { @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //imageDetail.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        System.out.println("matrix=" + savedMatrix.toString());
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        startPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
        mode = DRAG;
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
        if (oldDist > 10f) {
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(midPoint, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            } 
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                     if (mode == ZOOM) {
                        float newDist = spacing(event);
            if (newDist > 10f) {
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            float scale = newDist / oldDist;                          
            matrix.postScale(scale,    scale, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
            }
                        }
                    break;
                    }
        view.setImageMatrix(matrix); return true;
        }
    @SuppressLint
    ("FloatMath") private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
        } });
    }
}
```

Here's XML

```
 <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:scaleType="matrix"
           android:src="@drawable/k13"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need to post the code and describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: @Blacklight May be you can helpful this time